# Oracle DB Sequence Parallel processing - Multi threading

Tags: database, oracle, parallel-processing, sequence, nextval

I need to generate a unique number to attach it to the metadata of an object when a new object is created. The object metadata only has to be set from code using the framework library as the object is internally linked to multiple tables in the database and updating a column directly is not advised and risky. For this purpose, I am trying to use the Oracle DB sequence and use the nextval as the unique reference number. But to make this sequence generation more parallel, I wanted to introduce 10 sequencers with increments of 10 and starting with 1,2,3..,10 respectively, so that no sequence will generate a duplicate number. The idea is when 10000 objects are created at a time, I can split the load into 10 different sequences and process them in 10 batches in parallel.

But when I implemented this solution I can observe the single sequence implementation is more efficient than dividing into 10 different sequences.

The observation goes like this.

**CASE 1:**

Generation of 10 sequences from a single Sequencer took (10 sequence numbers from the same sequencer) - ~400 ms

Generation of 10 sequences from 10 separate sequencers took (1 number from each sequencer) - ~40 ms

**Case 2:**

Generation of 1000 sequences from a single Sequencer took (1000 sequence numbers from the same sequencer) - ~4600 ms

Generation of 1000 sequences from 10 separate sequencers took (100 numbers from each sequencer) - ~4200 ms

So the single sequence though appeared ten times slower, as the parallel requests increased, it managed to perform better whereas the multiple sequence implementation scaled linearly by 100 times and took the almost same time as a single sequence for 1000 sequence generations.

the cache size of all the sequencers here is the same and set to 100.

I would like to understand, do multiple sequencer implementation could help in parallel processing as I thought? If not, please explain why? and if it can, then where am I implementing this wrongly?

Thank you very much in advance for your time on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems needlessly complex. Simply increase the cache size of the one sequence so that it holds at least as many values as you might need in a single burst.

Querying multiple sequences will introduce a lot more overhead to the database kernel since each sequence and its cache must be loaded and maintained in memory, each query must be parsed and run separately, and those separate queries on separate objects will consume more of the library cache. Much more expensive than compiling one query and executing it more times with a properly tuned cache. In the end it will cause resource contention and not scale, and I would NOT advise going that route.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. Is there any sweet number that can be suggested like 2 sequencers or 3. that will help with parallel processing? it is expected to have multiple 10000 object creations at a time. so even if cache is given as 10000 It might not help much.

Comment: One sequence only. Tune the cache. Multiple sequences will cause unnecessary compute overhead and resource contention.

Comment: I got the point. I am going to use a single sequence alone for my need. but I really struggle to understand and grasp what actually happening in the background on DB end. I am searching for articles around but am not able to find something that I can understand. Could you please explain why we are not able to gain any time when we execute 10 different independent queries?

Comment: To my understanding.
Case 1: where only 1 query is executed multiple times.
It takes x secs to parse/compile
it takes y secs to execute
It taken z secs to load and update cache

So total time taken is x+y+z secs

Comment: Case 2: Where 10 different queries is executed multiple times.
even though it is a different query, it should be consuming almost same time for each query as case 1. i.e.,
It takes x secs to parse/compile
it takes y secs to execute
It taken z secs to load and update cache

Comment: And as oracle should be able to handle/execute multiple different queries in parallel when they are independent of each other, I was assuming even though the resourses are consumed for 10 different queries it should atlease benefit in time. Because how the single sequence query is being managed, the rest of the sequence queries shall also be managed in the similar way and by using multiple sequence providers we should be reducing the dependency of each request. Very sorry if my query/understanding is dumb.

Comment: With a single query run multiple times, the query is parsed and compiled *once*, placed in the library cache, and executed as often as necessary without further compilation overhead. With multiple queries, each one must be compiled *separately*, each one will take space in the library cache, reducing space for other SQL and making it more likely that any one query will get removed from the library cache and recompiled. You're using more CPU to manage the library cache, more CPU to do more compilations, and more memory to manage more sequence caches...

Comment: ...  Sooner or later contention in your library cache is going to become a problem if you try to scale up. Latches to compiled queries are limited, and they're expensive to swap in and out. If the library cache gets overloaded you'll start seeing other CPU wait times creep in to your performance metrics, and things will slow down for the entire system, not just your sequence queries. Oracle can handle a lot of things in parallel, but as a general rule it isn't a good idea to force this kind of parallelism if you don't have to when Oracle has provided a way to tune this performance already.